# jq (command-line JSON processor) merge multiple JSON strings from STDIN

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to merge two different JSON strings from STDIN (using pipe, not files) using jq command. Here's the command trying:

```bsh
curl  ipinfo.io api.ipify.org/?format=json 2>/dev/null | jq -s
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "ip": "139.162.244.103",
    "hostname": "businessproservices.com",
    "city": "London",
    "region": "England",
    "country": "GB",
    "loc": "51.5142,-0.0931",
    "postal": "EC2V",
    "org": "AS63949 Linode, LLC"
  },
  {
    "ip": "139.162.244.103"
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "ip": "139.162.244.103",
  "hostname": "businessproservices.com",
  "city": "London",
  "region": "England",
  "country": "GB",
  "loc": "51.5142,-0.0931",
  "postal": "EC2V",
  "org": "AS63949 Linode, LLC"
}
```

Comment: `curl  ipinfo.io | jq` will return expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `curl` command queries two hosts.  Each will return a JSON document.  `jq -s` will add these together as two entries in an array.  To get the first entry (which is what you're presenting as the expected output), simply request `first` (or `.[0]`) from `jq`, as in

```
curl -s ipinfo.io 'api.ipify.org/?format=json' | jq -s 'first'
```

or just use the first host from the start:

```
curl ipinfo.io
```

To actually *merge* the two document, apply the `jq` command `add` to the returned list:

```
curl -s ipinfo.io 'api.ipify.org/?format=json' | jq -s 'add'
```

Note that since a JSON object can't contain multiple keys with the same name, any later key will *replace* an equivalent earlier key, so that if your `jq -s` document is

```json
[
  {
    "ip": "139.162.244.103",
    "hostname": "businessproservices.com",
    "city": "London",
    "region": "England",
    "country": "GB",
    "loc": "51.5142,-0.0931",
    "postal": "EC2V",
    "org": "AS63949 Linode, LLC"
  },
  {
    "ip": "39.62.44.1",
    "country": "UK"
  }
]
```

then this would be merged as

```json
{
  "ip": "39.62.44.1",
  "hostname": "businessproservices.com",
  "city": "London",
  "region": "England",
  "country": "UK",
  "loc": "51.5142,-0.0931",
  "postal": "EC2V",
  "org": "AS63949 Linode, LLC"
}
```

when using `jq -s add` in place of `jq -s`.

Comment: Is this solution working for you? I had tried this but doesn't work for me, my jq version is jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe

Comment: @Pradeep With `jq -s 'add'`? Yes, it works for me using `jq` 1.6.  I can't unfortunately test with an earlier version easily.

Comment: for me it works with `jq 'add'` (without -s option)

Comment: @DirkHoffmann Yes, it would be enough if you passed the output of `jq -s` though `jq add`.  This is the same as using `jq -s add` though.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo '
[
  {
    "ip": "139.162.244.103",
    "hostname": "businessproservices.com",
    "city": "London",
    "region": "England",
    "country": "GB",
    "loc": "51.5142,-0.0931",
    "postal": "EC2V",
    "org": "AS63949 Linode, LLC"
  },
  {
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "country": "UK",
    "additional": "added Value"
  }
]' | jq  "add"
```

result

````
{
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "hostname": "businessproservices.com",
  "city": "London",
  "region": "England",
  "country": "UK",
  "loc": "51.5142,-0.0931",
  "postal": "EC2V",
  "org": "AS63949 Linode, LLC",
  "additional": "added Value"
}```
````

Comment: Yes, if you're starting with what you get from `curl URL1 URL2 | jq -s`, then it will be enough with `jq add`.  Note that the output of `curl URL1 URL2` is a set of two JSON objects (`{...} {...}`), not an array of two objects (`[{...},{...}]`).  The user is showing the output _after passing the `curl` output through `jq -s`_.